# match diagonal elements: list converted to a square matrix for tic-tac-toe game

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to match diagonal elements of a list called 'grid[]' or elements of tic-tac-toe board input as one dimension. I want to make the board size dynamic and be able to check for 3 by 3, 4 by 4, 5 by 5 and so on.

I have already written code for checking columns and rows:

```
import math
grid = ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
dim = (round(math.sqrt(len(grid))))   
count4 = 0
for i in range(dim):
    if all(grid[count4 + i] == "X" for i in range(dim)):
        count3 = 0
        print ("Player X win")
        print ("-------------")
        for i in range(dim):
            print(grid[0 + count3 : dim + count3])
            count3 += dim
        print ("-------------")
    count4 += dim
count4 = 0
for i in range(dim):
    if all(grid[count4 + i] == "X" for i in range(0, (dim * dim), dim )):
        count3 = 0
        print ("Player X win")
        print ("-------------")
        for i in range(dim):
            print(grid[0 + count3 : dim + count3])
            count3 += dim
        print ("-------------")
    count4 += 1
```

I am not able to figure out how do I check for diagonals (left and right). Can someone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works, at least for `dim = 3` and `dim = 4`:

```
diagonal1 = [(dim + 1) * i for i in range(dim)]
diagonal2 = [(i + 1) * (dim - 1) for i in range(dim)]

if all(grid[d] == "X" for d in diagonal1):
    print ("Player X win")
    count3 = 0
    print ("-------------")
    for i in range(dim):
        print(grid[0 + count3 : dim + count3])
        count3 += dim
    print ("-------------")


if all(grid[d] == "X" for d in diagonal2):
    count3 = 0
    print ("Player X win")
    print ("-------------")
    for i in range(dim):
        print(grid[0 + count3 : dim + count3])
        count3 += dim
    print ("-------------")
```